# Text into SVG path to animate in CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, jquery-animate

It's been days that I am trying to figure out how I can animate a text previously typed (and converted into a Path) as a SVG file in Illustrator.

I've followed some tutorials ([this one](https://medium.com/@gordonnl/stylised-line-animations-ded23320ffe5) and tried to reproduce [that one](http://bit.ly/1KqvYtP)) without success. I don't know where to start. I know I will have to make a mask in Illustrator to do it (because I want to use a font), but I really don't get it.

Do you guys have any idea how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: This question would do a lot better on graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try vivus js. SVG Animation Library